# How can I map Observable to Single in RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have `Observable<State> state`
and this piece of code `

```
Flowable<.> loadData(){
return state.toFlowable(Latest).flatmap(this::fetchData()) }`
```

where `fetchData()` return `Flowable`

but what if we have `fetchData()` with `Single` return type
and loadData() return Single<.>

How can I map Observable to Single?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take first item with `.take(1)` and transform to single with following methods:

- `.single(defaultItem)`
- `.singleElement()`
- `.singleOrError()`

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working solution:

```
 loadDataSingle()
            .subscribeBy(
                    onSuccess = { println("This is your single data $it") },
                    onError = { println("We have a problem") }
            )


fun loadDataSingle(): Single<String> {
    return getState().singleOrError()
            .flatMap {
                fetchDataSingle()
            }
}

fun fetchDataSingle(): Single<String> {
    return Single.just("This is fetching your single data")
}
```

Or you could do this Single.fromObservable and wrap the call inside it

```
   fun loadDataSingle(): Single<String> {
    return Single.fromObservable(getState())
            .flatMap { fetchDataSingle() }

   }
```

Comment: If `getState()` emit more than one element, exception will be signalled.

Comment: @lbasek and that is why we handle `onError` in case that does happen. Do you have any alternative solution for this?

Comment: I think it’s just a matter of implementation. You can take just first element  (`.take(1)`) and avoid exception here.